# Anaconda Jupyter Custom CSS

Tags: anaconda, jupyter

Anyone know if and how this is possible within the Jupyter that comes with Anaconda? (i.e. Customizing the Jupyter theme via CSS in Anacconda).

http://sherifsoliman.com/2016/01/11/theming-ipython-jupyter-notebook/

I tried putting a css file here: Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\tests\dotipython\custom\custom.css

But can't see any changes and not sure if this is even the right place for it.

Comment: I put the `custom.css` file in `~/.jupyter/custom/` and it works well. By the way, I'm using a Mac and I installed python3 with Homebrew, and other packages with pip3.

Comment: Is that within Anaconda? Can you post the full path within the Anaconda directory? I didn't see a .jupyter/custom/ folder in there on Windows.

Comment: Not within Anaconda (I'm not using it). I thought there is a folder on Windows which functions similar to the folder `~/.jupyter/custom/` on macOS or Linux. Maybe I was wrong.

Comment: My understanding is that you can install Jupyter directly in which case it will create  ~/.jupyter/custom/ or rely on the one that comes with Anaconda. It's this latter scenario I'm struggling with.

Comment: @user1761806 - I've also run into this problem. Please let us know if you sovled it.

Comment: It's hacky and not an answer to your question, but I've changed the width of the canvas to 100% in Chrome by using the inspect and editing the style sheet. The changes are gone upon re-load, but you don't tend to re-load the page very often when using a notebook.

Answer (score 2):

Given that my conda is installed on

```
/Users/myusername/anaconda
```

what I did is to copy the custom.css into

```
/Users/myusername/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/
```

(note that I installed Conda for Python 3.6)
After that just restart your `jupyter notebook`, it should be updated to the new theme

Edit: my custom.css is created using Jupyter-Themer.

Answer (score 0):

you can put it on C:/Users/User/.jupyter/custom/custom.css

works for me